# While loop stuck at await asyncio.sleep(1) permanetly within python flet module

Tags: python, while-loop, async-await, python-asyncio

I am trying to make an asynchronous block of code to work within a flet module based app. The program starts just fine, but the async countdown(t): function stops working when the line await asyncio.sleep(1) kicks in. The program just dies there. What I want to do is to increment a number visible on the GUI every 10 minutes but while doing so I do not want my app to wait between these working minutes. I want the async function to work seperately and at the same time while the other functions are doing their tasks.

```
import flet
    from flet import Page, Theme, ElevatedButton,TextField,         AlertDialog, TextButton, Text, Row, IconButton,icons,Column
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    import time
    import PIL
import asyncio  



def main(page: Page):
    theme = Theme()
    page.vertical_alignment = "center"
    number_to_inc = Text(value="0.00000000", width=170)
    global number_int, t
    t=20
    number_int= 0.00000000

    async def liberated(t):
        print(f"liberated async{t}")
        task1 = asyncio.ensure_future(countdown(t))

    async def auto_inc():
        global number_int
        number_int+= 0.00000001
        value = "{:.8f}".format(norion_token)
        print("otomatik artis değer işlendi")
        number_to_inc.value = f"{value}" + " Here it is"
        page.update()
        return await countdown(t=20)

    async def countdown(t):
        print(f"countdown async {t}")
        while t >= 0:
            mins, secs = divmod(t, 60)
            timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
            print(timer, end="\r")
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            t -= 1
            
        return await auto_inc()
    # 4579

    asyncio.run(liberated(t))

    if page.web:
        add_widgets()
        print("WEBROWSER")

    elif page.platform == "windows":
        add_widgets()
        print(page.platform)

    elif page.platform == "android":
        add_widgets()
        print(page.platform)


#flet.app(target=main, view=flet.WEB_BROWSER)
flet.app(target=main)
```

Comment: `countdown` doesn't return anything, but it should. `asyncio.run(liberated(t))` never runs because it comes after `return`. I don't think it's stuck. I think it isn't running in the first place. If it was you would get `await` errors.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy I miscopied it to here. It is working fine until await asyncio.sleep(1) works. Then the code stops working without errors. I have put some print functions before and after the line.